# Using Plotly Mapboxes Offline in R

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I'm working on an R shiny app, which uses ggplot to overlay a series of lines on a map of the world.  Since the lines can overlap, I have a control panel which dynamically updates a checkbox input to make sure I have one checkbox item per map line, with which I can hide/reveal lines.

I think it would be cleaner and more user friendly if I were to use plotly mapboxes.  Not only does this look nicer and allow the user greater freedom to navigate the map, it also means I don't have an ever growing checkbox region taking up half the app window.  With the [example on the plotly website](https://plotly.com/r/lines-on-mapbox/), I've been able to prove to myself that this looks and feels better.

The problem is, I need my app to also be able to work without an internet connection.  For my old ggplot method, this is fine, as I was able to download some specific tilesets with ggmap::get_stamenmap(), convert those to an rds, and read them offline with readRDS from base.

Is there a way that I could continue to use plotly's mapboxes offline?  Would I be on the right track with the downloaded tilesets that I already have?

---

I've just added a post about this [here on the plotly forums](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-use-mapboxes-in-shiny-while-offline/78342).  I want to keep these posts linked in case somebody finds one in the future, and can get useful information from the other one.

Comment: This seemed interesting, so I did a brief search. I found a [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/zq7svx/offline_plotting_of_maps/) that suggests one path would be to have a local tile server: https://community.plotly.com/t/plotly-v4-dash-offline-map/33876 and https://community.plotly.com/t/offline-scattergeo-plots-not-working/43790. (Another option? https://github.com/burakbayramli/simplegeomap.) I've done none of that, sorry, just reposting for discussion.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the suggestions!  Unfortunately, I've also come across that reddit thread and the plotly community posts.  Those seem geared more towards Dash (Python), and aren't necessarily 1:1 with R.  However, the idea of hosting a local offline tile server is a possibility, but it's something I'm unfamiliar with and was hoping to keep on the back burner.  Simplegeomap certainly has a good description, but it looks like it's also for Python.  Maybe I can find an R version of it?  But I was hoping to use Plotly to have the integrated line selections.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I didn't derive the solution I was expecting, but I did come up with something functional.

I was able to take the locally downloaded tileset, plot it with ggmap and geom_sf for my lines, and just feed that into a ggplotly and renderPlotly.  This is similar enough to what I was hoping to achieve that I'm not going to continue pursuing mapboxes.